# Xcopy doesn't copy, just 0?

Tags: xcopy

By using the command below it works, but without copying anything.

```
xcopy "F:/*.*" "G:/some Thing" /s /e /c /h /i /d /r /k /y /z 
PAUSE
```

It shows:

> 0 Files copied

It's the same with or without switches. Maybe some switches or commands needs to be changed?

Comment: You didn't mention which OS you're using, but I'll just throw this out there for anyone not aware: On Windows Vista or higher, Robocopy is a much better alternative.

Comment: Win7x64, I will take a look for Robocopy. Beside the bus like USB/Sata etc. it could be good to know how to set it for using it with e.g. a Quadcore multithreaded cpu. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using [the wrong slash](http://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/) (`/`) in your paths, making them invalid.  Xcopy doesn't know how to handle those invalid paths, and therefore copies no files.

Use the backslash (`\`) instead.

i.e.:

```
xcopy "F:\*.*" "G:\some Thing" /s /e /c /h /i /d /r /k /y /z
```

Comment: Also, there is  potentially a case where the `/d` option might not copy files, but I think this is answer is correct.

Comment: @yorik I agree about `/d`.  I only included the OP's switches in the example to make it match theirs. :)

Comment: Yes, now it seems to work. Just to see the result of backup, if the switches are okay. Thank you very much